# Is telling the user that the account has been locked a security risk?

Tags: security, authentication

I have a website where users can log in to access restricted pages. I'm trying to make this as secure as I can so I try to follow "best practises".

To reduce the risk of brute force attacks against the login page I only allow the user to attempt to log in a set number of times. If the user fails to log in 3 times the account is locked and must be unlocked before the user can log in again.

**My question is whether I should tell the user on the login page when the account has been locked?**

From a usability perspective it seems like the right thing to do to show a message to tell user that the account has been locked. But wouldn't that mean that an attacker could use that to find existing usernames?

After a single failed login attempt I only show the user a message that "the username and/or the password is incorrect", i.e. I never tell the user exactly what was wrong. I do this because otherwise an attacker can find existing usernames by trying lots of them and see when the error messages changes from "wrong username" to "wrong password". This is recommended by articles about security that I've read. But wouldn't I end up in the same situation if I told the user when an account is locked? An attacker could try lots of usernames three times, and if a message that the account is locked is shown the attacker knows that there is an account with that username.

I will always send an email to the user who's account has been locked, but I believe the user will not necessarily see that immediately and may keep trying to login even though the account has been locked. I think that's going to create some annoyance among the users, especially if the know they are using the correct credentials and still get a message that the credentials are invalid (when in fact the account is locked so the credentials don't matter).

So how should I do this? How have you implemented this yourself?

Comment: lock out on 3 attempts: built-in DOS attack. All I need to do is attempt 3 times and I locked out an user. *Any* user.

Comment: Blacklist the attempter, not user, that is much better approach. Of course, identifying it is non trivial eg. blacklist the IP works, but only partially.

Comment: Lengthier discussion: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/487/why-do-sites-implement-locking-after-3-failed-password-attempts

Comment: @RemusRusanu: Thanks for your comments and for the link :) That's a lot of good points to consider. However, I'm still interested in a direct answer to my question if I still choose to implement some kind of lockout feature.

Comment: Hi - was my answer useful?

Answer (score 1):

> From a usability perspective it seems like the right thing to do to show a message to tell user that the account has been locked. But wouldn't that mean that an attacker could use that to find existing usernames?

Depends how you've implemented it - if you only show the message for valid accounts, then this would be a [username enumeration](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_User_Enumeration_and_Guessable_User_Account_%28OWASP-AT-002%29) vulnerability.

If however you store all login attempts separately from your users table, then you can show a fake account locked message for invalid accounts too.

e.g. log all attempts

```
Date/Time        Username    Successful
06/06/14 10:00   foo         false
06/06/14 10:01   foo         false
06/06/14 10:02   bar         false
06/06/14 10:03   foo         false
```

where `bar` is a valid user and `foo` isn't - but if someone tries to log in as foo again now you could examine the last 30 minutes of the log and show `Foo: Your account has been locked.`.

Also note that this could also be seen as a type of DoS attack against valid users if you then lock them out. A better approach might be to rate limit repeat attempts against the same username or from the same IP address. This should be done in parallel to prevent an attacker from using multiple threads to defeat your throttling.